# Loading jQuery Plug-in doesn't work

Tags: jquery, function, jquery-plugins, plugins, loading

After I finished my first jQuery PLug-In I began to develop this one. But somehow this plug-in doesn't work.. I really don't understand what's wrong because I am sure I followed all the rules for plug-in making.

EDIT: By "Doesn't work" I mean that nothing happens to the element on the webpage. It doesn't even return an error. it just doesn't work.

The jQuery Plug-In is based on a normal javascript source:
You can see a working example [here](http://www.ximore.com/test/loader.html)
and a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/M8Wta/)

The examples has been made with the javascript, not the jQuery Plug-In

this is my plugin

```
 ;(function($){

     // We name the function loader
     $.fn.loader = function (options) {

         // Default settings - can be replaced by options
         var defaults = {
             speed: 5,
             width: 50,
             height: 50,
             totalFrames: 19,
             frameWidth: 50,
             color: 'white',
             loaderTimeout: false,
             index: 0,
             Xpos: 0,
             frameDelay: 0
         }

         // Extend the options and defaults to variables
         var opts = $.extend(defaults, options);

         // We locate the loader Image
         var loaderImage = '../../_resources/loading/loading_sprites_'+ opts.color + '_' + opts.height + '.png';

         // Now start the Function
         return this.each(function() {

             // The original element is defined with a variable
             var element = $(this);
             var frameDelay = opts.frameDelay;

             // We start out by defining the beginning of the animation
             function startLoader() {

                 // The element is giving the right width and height to contain
                 // the loading animation, and the loaderImage source as background
                 element.width(opts.width).height(opts.height).css('background-image', 'url('+loaderImage+')');

                 // We calculate the Frames Per Second
                 FPS = Math.round(100/opts.speed);
                 frameDelay = 1 / FPS;

                 // And start the animation
                 setTimeout('continueAnimation()', frameDelay / 1000);

             }

             // To keep the animation on going we need to define a function
             // that continuesly repeat the sprites
             function continueAnimation() {

                 var Xpos = opts.Xpos;
                 var index = opts.index;

                 // The X-position is defined based on how wide the frame is
                 Xpos += opts.frameWidth;

                 // index is defined by continuelsy counting
                 index += 1;

                 // if index counts to more or equal to the amount of frames defined
                 if (index >= opts.totalFrames) {
                     Xpos = 0; // ... we set the X-position to be 0
                     index = 0; // ... and the index too
                 }

                 // We change the position og the sprite to give the illusion
                 // of an animation going on
                 element.css('background-position', Xpos + 'px 0');

                 // And finally we are going to ask our function to repeat itself.
                 setTimeout('continueAnimation()', frameDelay * 1000);

             }

             // Before anything we want the sprites to be pre-loaded
             function imageLoader(source, start) {

                 var loaderTimeout = opts.loaderTimeout;

                 // First we clear Timout
                 clearTimeout(loaderTimeout);
                 loaderTimeout = 0;

                 // Then we generate a new image (the sprites)
                 genImage = new Image();

                 // When the image is loaded we want to start the animation
                 genImage.onload = function() {loaderTimeout = setTimeout(start, 0)};

                 // If we can't locate the sprite image, we prepare an error function
                 genImage.onerror = new Function('alert(\'Could not load the image\')');

                 // And we define the image source 
                 genImage.src = source;
             }

             // This command starts the whole animation
             new imageLoader(loaderImage, 'startAnimation()');

         });
     }

 })(jQuery);
```

I call my plug-in like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.loader').loader({
        color: 'blue'
    })
});
```

Comment: Is that a stray ; right at the beginning?

Comment: @user1394965 ya it is and its commonly used for plugin coding

Comment: Please expand on "it doesn't work"

Comment: Probably not related, but you're overwriting your defaults with your options on each invocation. You should pass an empty object `{}` as the first argument to `$.extend()`.

Comment: Can't answer your question, but you have once: setTimeout('continueAnimation()', frameDelay * 1000); and once: setTimeout('continueAnimation()', frameDelay / 1000); is that intended?

Answer (score 2):

Your code says:

```
new imageLoader(loaderImage, 'startAnimation()');
```

And that second parameter passes that to `setTimeout`:

```
 genImage.onload = function() {loaderTimeout = setTimeout(start, 0)};
```

But your method is called `startLoader()`

As an aside: You should avoid passing strings to `setTimeout`/`setInterval`. Its eval in disguise and [eval is evil!](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/11/01/53329.aspx)

Comment: THANKS... didn't solve the problem, but I definitely didn't see that I had made a Typo.. Any advice on what to write instead (about the setTimeout/setInterval)

Comment: As for the strings, pass a reference to the function itself, rather than a string. eg `setTimeout(startAnimation,0)` in place of `setTimeout('startAnimation()',0)`

Answer (score 0):

is jquery-ui an option?

If you are just wanting to learn to write your own widget, learn what 'this' references, and in general do things the 'not easy' way, then ignore this answer :)

If this is for work and stopping you from going home, I highly recommend the [jquery-ui widget factory](http://ajpiano.com/widgetfactory).Try this (off to a meeting and will throw in a jsfiddle if I can get them time) :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.loader').loader({
        color: 'blue'
    })
});
$.widget("pj.loader",{
  options:{
             speed: 5,
             width: 50,
             height: 50,
             totalFrames: 19,
             frameWidth: 50,
             color: "white",
             loaderTimeout: false,
             index: 0,
             Xpos: 0,
             frameDelay: 0,
             imgBase: "../../_resources/loading/loading_sprites_"
         },
//called once and only once per widget
  _create: function(){
    var self = this,
        selectedElement = self.element;
      self.options.loaderImage = self.options.imgBase + self.options.color + '_' + self.options.height + '.png';
      self.imageLoader(self.options.loaderImage, self.startAnimation);
},
  startAnimation : function(){
var self = this;
// The element is giving the right width and height to contain
                 // the loading animation, and the loaderImage source as background
                 element.width(self.options.width).height(self.options.height).css('background-image', 'url('+self.options.loaderImage+')');

                 // We calculate the Frames Per Second
                 FPS = Math.round(100/self.options.speed);
                 self.options.frameDelay = 1 / FPS;

                 // And start the animation
                 setTimeout(self.continueAnimation, self.options.frameDelay / 1000);
},
continueAnimation : function(){
 var self = this,
     Xpos = self.options.Xpos,
     index = self.options.index;

                 // The X-position is defined based on how wide the frame is
                 Xpos += self.options.frameWidth;

                 // index is defined by continuelsy counting
                 index += 1;

                 // if index counts to more or equal to the amount of frames defined
                 if (index >= self.options.totalFrames) {
                     Xpos = 0; // ... we set the X-position to be 0
                     index = 0; // ... and the index too
                 }

                 // We change the position og the sprite to give the illusion
                 // of an animation going on
                 element.css('background-position', Xpos + 'px 0');

                 // And finally we are going to ask our function to repeat itself.
                 setTimeout('continueAnimation()', frameDelay * 1000);
},
imageLoader : function(source, start){
var self = this,
  loaderTimeout = self.options.loaderTimeout;

                 // First we clear Timout
                 clearTimeout(loaderTimeout);
                 loaderTimeout = 0;

                 // Then we generate a new image (the sprites)
                 genImage = new Image();

                 // When the image is loaded we want to start the animation
                 genImage.onload = function() {loaderTimeout = setTimeout(start, 0)};

                 // If we can't locate the sprite image, we prepare an error function
                 genImage.onerror = new Function('alert(\'Could not load the image\')');

                 // And we define the image source 
                 genImage.src = source;
},
//optional, called every time $('selector').loader() is called
  _init: function(){},

//recommended optional, called on $('loader.selector').remove() or similar.
//you should undo all your changes / events in create
  _destroy: function(){}
});
```

Comment: it tells me there is an error at this line: `self.options.loaderImage = self.options.imgBase + self.options.color + '_' + self.options.height + '.png';`

Comment: I'll have to take a look after my meeting, check the new options.imgbase swapped ' with "

Comment: I have some questions.. I believe that it is not possible to give a variable a name like: `self.options.loaderImage`. Beside that `frameDelay` is also an option and since it has not been put to a local variable, it should be written like this `self.options.frameDelay`. I am just a newbie so this is just me wondering, because it doesn't seem logic to me.

Comment: Hi hope you have had a fantastic christmas and great new year.. Could you please show me fiddle of it now maybe? It would mean a lot to me..